Use a tf variable in a user_data.tpl file
I'm deploying an eks cluster with terraform, to start the nodes for the eks managed node group, I defined a user_data.tpl file.
    eks_managed_node_groups = {
    "${var.cluster_name}_managed_node_group" = {
      ami_release_version           = var.ami_version
      create_launch_template        = true
      launch_template_name          = var.launch_template_name
      user_data_template_path       = "./user_data.tpl"
    ...

Inside the user_data file I'm trying to download a .zip file from artifactorycloud and for that i required to pass the username and password:
sudo wget --http-user=${USERNAME} --http-password=${PASSWORD} https://artifactorycloud.mypage.com/artifactory/l-generic-agent-binaries/splunk-agent/aws/latest/AWS_NIX_latest_UF.zip

I already created those vars and add them the values.
variable "USERNAME" {
  description = "Username for artifactorycloud"
  type        = string
}
    
variable "PASSWORD" {
  description = "Password for artifactorycloud"
  type        = string
}

But It seems that the values is not being taken in the user_data.tpl. How can I do that?

you need to use the templatefile function, passing it the template file name and a map of vars to substitue https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile

As Chris Doyle wrote in his comment, you should probably use the templatefile built-in function. However, it looks like those are environment variables. If those need to be referenced in the same way, you would need to use a double $ sign in front:
 sudo wget --http-user=$${USERNAME} --http-password=$${PASSWORD} https://artifactorycloud.mypage.com/artifactory/l-generic-agent-binaries/splunk-agent/aws/latest/AWS_NIX_latest_UF.zip

If you do decide to use the templatefile function, that part of the code should look something like:
eks_managed_node_groups = {
"${var.cluster_name}_managed_node_group" = {
  ami_release_version           = var.ami_version
  create_launch_template        = true
  launch_template_name          = var.launch_template_name
  user_data_template_path       = templatefile("${path.root}/user_data.tpl", {
   USERNAME = var.USERNAME
   PASSWORD = var.PASSWORD
})
...


I got this error:
Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at "MIME-Version:
│ 1.0\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed;
│ boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="\n\n--==MYBOUNDARY==\nContent-Type:
│ text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"\n\n#!/bin/bash\nset

Where is the tpl file located? Is this part of the config a part of a module?
